# How to auto raise and resolve tasks in jira with jenkins tool

Tags: jenkins

How to automate that If a build or test fails in jenkins, it should raise an issue like story or task in jira, when that problem it should auto resolve without manual interaction

Answer (score 0):

You can use jira api to create an issue and you resolve them by using an API. But you maintain mapping between jira issue code failure test case.

Comment: can you explain in more detail